# Calculate sum of all child values called "quantity" in my Users node

Tags: java, android

I want to calculate sum of all "quantity" values in **Users** node and put the total value in the line chart graph.Can any one please help me,
Here  is what i have done.

```
DatabaseReference rootRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    DatabaseReference unicaribeRef = rootRef.child("Users");
    ValueEventListener eventListener = new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
            //int total = 0;
            for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                int value = ds.getValue(Integer.class);
                //int result = Integer.parseInt(value);
                total =+ value;
            }
            Log.d("TAG", String.valueOf(total));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
    };
    unicaribeRef.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(eventListener);

    yAxes.add(new Entry(total, 0));
    yAxes.add(new Entry(50,1));
    yAxes.add(new Entry(40,2));
    yAxes.add(new Entry(60,3));
    yAxes.add(new Entry(20,4));

    String[] xaxes = new String[xAxes.size()];

    for(int i=0;i<xAxes.size();i++)
    {
        xaxes[i] = xAxes.get(i).toString();
    }

    LineDataSet lineDataSet = new LineDataSet(yAxes,"Crops");
    lineDataSet.setDrawCircles(true);
    lineDataSet.setColor(Color.BLUE);

    lineDataSets.add(lineDataSet);

    lineChart.setData(new LineData(xaxes,lineDataSets));

    lineChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(40f);
    lineChart.setTouchEnabled(true);
    lineChart.setDragEnabled(true);
```

[This is my database](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2Jpq.png)

Comment: You should add more details like what problem you're facing with your code right now.

Comment: When i run it i don’t get any errors but total quantity value reads as “0” on the graph while data on database is “30”

Comment: Are you able to get data correctly from database?